# Show special backend content for certain roles

Tags: user-roles

I think I'm pretty close to what I need, but just need a little direction.
I'm trying to show a content widget in the backend to users of a certain role. Right now, I'm just testing it out with a user that has a role of `subscriber`.

**This works perfect :**

```
<?php 
    // Add a widget to the WordPress dashboard
    function wpc_dashboard_widget_function() 
    {
        // Do whatever you want to render in here
        echo '<div>
        <h3>Special Offer One</h3>
        <div>Special Offer Text will go here!</div>
        </div>';
    }
    function wpc_add_dashboard_widgets() 
    {
        wp_add_dashboard_widget('wp_dashboard_widget', 'Special Offers Just For   
        Vendors', 'wpc_dashboard_widget_function');
    }
    add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpc_add_dashboard_widgets' );
?>
```

But that shows it to all users. I would like to only show to a certain role and was trying to use:

```
if (!current_user_can('subscriber')):
endif;
```

along with it, but it just screws things up and the special widget doesn't show at all for anyone.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible Reasons -

1. `current_user_can()` function needs an input of a **capability** not **user role**, though it works sometime but we should not use user role as a input to this function.
2. you're passing the `subscriber` object to function which is a lowest possible role we can have on Wordpress. That's why `!current_user_can('subscriber')` makes it unavailable for all.

Have a look at Wordpress Documentation of [Capabilities Vs Roles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table) table, Use that table to determine which capability you can use to hide it or show to particular role. To show the box to `Editor` you can use capability `moderate_comments` .

```
E.g -   if ( current_user_can ('moderate_comments') ) 
        {
            //To see this visible you should have at-least Editor privileges
        }
```

#### Note -

I recommend using  `wp_get_current_user()` function. This can be used to grab user role and show specific content. The content will be available to that user only, Not even users with higher privileges can see it.

```
   // Add a widget to the WordPress dashboard
    function wpc_dashboard_widget_function() 
    {
        global $wp_roles;
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $roles = $current_user->roles;
        $role = array_shift($roles);

        if($role == 'administrator')
        {
            // This is only for Admins
            echo '<div><h4>Special Offer One</h4><div>Special Offer Text will go here!</div></div>';
        }
    }
    function wpc_add_dashboard_widgets() 
    {
        wp_add_dashboard_widget('wp_dashboard_widget', 'Special Offers Just For   
        Vendors', 'wpc_dashboard_widget_function');
    }
    add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpc_add_dashboard_widgets' );
```

Comment: Ok, great! Thank you! The first example with using if current_user_can works great, and thank you for explaining it to me. I did try to use your noted, bottom recommendation, but it didn't work, really. It shows to all users, plus didn't echo out the full html.